# Global variable storage or maybe Singleton Class for OOP Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am still checking out object orientated programming in javascript so i need a short starting help. Currently i am using Javascript classes that is representating a page (canvas) with registered listeners.

Now i want to number a id per page like newSite-1, newSite-2, newSite-3.... every time a new page is created. For this purpose i want to access a global counter.

Can so. check out my code and tell me the best place where to put such a variable and how to access it?

Thank you very much!

```
    /**
     * This Object is the new Page that will be created to enter tabulature

     */
    var Page = function () {
        this.typeName='Page';

        var newPage = document.createElement("canvas");
    newPage.id = "newSite";
    newPage.width=canvas.width;
    newPage.height=canvas.height;
    newPage.className = "tabulaturenCanvasCSS";
    document.body.appendChild(newPage);

    this.canvas=newPage;

    this.context = newPage.getContext('2d');
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        console.log('Bin da');
        this.registerListeners();
        this.redraw();
    };

    Page.prototype = {

            getTypeName: function () {
            return this.typeName;
        },  

        registerListeners: function() {
               this.canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
                   var x = e.x || e.clientX,
                       y = e.y || e.clientY;

                   this.loc = windowToCanvas(canvas, x, y);

                   e.preventDefault();

                   // console.log(loc.x+':'+loc.y)
                };          
        },

        drawGrid: function(color, stepx, stepy) {
         if(document.getElementById("cbShowGrid").checked)
         {
             this.context.save();

             this.context.shadowColor = undefined;
             this.context.shadowBlur = 0;
             this.context.shadowOffsetX = 0;
             this.context.shadowOffsetY = 0;

             this.context.strokeStyle = color;
             this.context.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
             this.context.lineWidth = 0.5;
             this.context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);

             for (var i = stepx + 0.5; i < context.canvas.width; i += stepx) {
                 this.context.beginPath();
                 this.context.moveTo(i, 0);
                 this.context.lineTo(i, context.canvas.height);
                 this.context.stroke();
             }

             for (var i = stepy + 0.5; i < context.canvas.height; i += stepy) {
                 this.context.beginPath();
                 this.context.moveTo(0, i);
                 this.context.lineTo(context.canvas.width, i);
                 this.context.stroke();
             }

            this.context.restore();
         }
       },    

        redraw: function() {
               this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
               this.drawGrid('lightgray', 10, 10);
       }
}
```

I have a index.html where i include the file an instantiate the objects:

And additionally there is a

var aNewPage=new Page();
pages.push(aNewPage); // Put them to an array

Comment: If the code is working as expected and objective of this question is improvements/optimizations, [CodeReviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the right place.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that link! Except one thing it is working - i need to number the IDs like newSite-1, newSite-2 ... etc . So i need a global place.

Comment: In that case, you can look into `localStorage`, `SessionStorage` or `cookies`. Every storage place has its pros and cons. Do check before using them

Comment: Thanks i think sessionStorage is the best way for me because i only want to keep values during the session. I hope there is no connection to the server session? I.e. when a PHP script says session_destroy() will this take affect on the sessionStorage?